# leading zero to decimal point if it is the first button pressed

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks the value of a textbox and adds a decimal point into the next place if there is not already a decimal point that exists.
What I'd like to do is have it so that if the decimal point button is the first button pressed, it will display as "0." in the textbox as opposed to just a "."

Here is my current decimal point code:

```
function decimalPoint()
{
    var rText = document.getElementById('resultText').value;

    if(rText.indexOf('.') !== -1)
    {
       // Ignore additional decimal point requests
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('resultText').value += '.'
    }
}
```

Any pointers on how to make this happen or if there is a better way to code this for the same result, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
function decimalPoint() {
  input = document.getElementById("decimalTest");
  if (input.value) {
    if (!input.value.includes("."))
      input.value += ".";
  } else {
    input.value = "0.";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="decimalTest"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="decimalPoint()" value="Add Decimal"/>
```

You could probably simplify this further, but it does the job.

Comment: Legend! Thanks heaps... Work's perfect! :-)